# I converted jQuery to JavaScript but I have questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I converted an old Wordpress Plugin of mine from jQuery to plain JavaScript using a cheat sheet. I was very surprised that it seems to work right out of the box on my first try.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('.comment-list > li .comment-reply').each(function () {

            var reply = this;

            /* collect every comment which needs a reply link */
            var allchildren = $(reply).parent().children('.children').children().find(".comment-content");

            $.each(allchildren, function (index, value) {
                $(reply).clone().appendTo(value);
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Became this:

```
const replybtns = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-list > li .comment-reply");

for (var i = 0; i < replybtns.length; i++) {
    var replybtn = replybtns[i];
    var replybtncp = replybtn.cloneNode(true);
    var cc = replybtn.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.children div.comment-content');
    var lastcc = cc[Object.keys(cc)[Object.keys(cc).length - 1]];
    lastcc.appendChild(replybtncp);
}
```

This copies all reply links of all level 1 nested comments and appends them to the last comment.

Is this code okay? Is it really that simple? I tested it with firefox and chrome, and it seems to work.

Comment: If it works, it works. If you're looking to refine it, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com. My one initial suggestion would be `let/const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Oh thank you! I did not know that website! Thanks!

Comment: But I see that your code is not the same, so I will prepare an answer...

Comment: I posted it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257199/copy-the-reply-button-to-each-comment-thread-in-wordpress-converted-from-jquery =) But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major difference is that the jQuery code calls `appendTo(value);` potentially multiple times per `reply` (i.e. per outer-loop iteration), depending on whether there are multiple matches found for the `.comment-content` selector.

But the plain JS version does not have an inner loop and only calls `appendChild` once per outer-loop iteration.

Some other minor differences:

- the jQuery code is running in a handler to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. (Note that its outer anonymous function is a useless wrapper, and the second one could be `jQuery(function($) {...`). The JS code doesn't have this feature.
- The use of `Object.keys(cc)` in the plain JS code is unnecessary. Getting the last element from a node list can be done in an easier way. However, this is something the jQuery code is not doing (getting the last element).
- The jQuery `children` method is not exactly reflected in the plain JS code, as a `querySelectorAll('.children div.comment-content')` can in theory find `.children` matches that are not at the level right under the node that this is called on.
- The jQuery code does not require that the `.comment-content` matches are `div` elements.

Comment: Thank you. I knew some of these and made the code simpler on purpose. But this helps a lot! =)

Comment: "The use of Object.keys(cc) in the plain JS code is unnecessary. Getting the last element from a node list can be done in an easier way." Thanks for the hint! But how? I tried ":last-child" as selector but it does not work. Many thanks again! =)

Comment: `cc[cc.length-1]`